# is using an ssh tunnel adequate protextion when using public wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh-tunnel

I am going to be traveling and on my tablet I use an ssh tunnel to browse the internet. Mainly so I can monitor my own traffic and see whay info APS are sending about me. So, will using an ssh tunnel on my device or a vpn be adequate protection against people sniffing my data while using public WiFi networks?

Comment: Is that an Android tablet? If yes, I prefer Openvpn Connect.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to use the always on VPN feature